# Wordpress Loop Dected, infinite loop -> sometimes?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns, infinite-loop

I have wordpress site and sometimes, lets say 10%-15% of the time i open the website it displays Loop Detected with the default message that an infinite loop has been detected etc...

I have googled the problem ofc but i got an impression that when people get this error they cant access their site at all...i find it baffling that this error happens only occasionally??

Also i have the correct domain and site name as http://domain.com (some people stated the problem was caused if they put www. )

Any ideas? Could it be due to DNS settings somehow?

Comment: Have you added anything to the htaccess file?

Comment: What kind of loop? is it a redirection infinte loop? like a page that redirects to itself ?

Comment: No htaccess file present...none came with the latest wordpress installations...also this didnt cause any problems on any previouse wp sites.I tried adding a htaccess fiel but probably with wrong params because the site doesnt open then.

Comment: @Geo The server terminated an operation because it encountered an infinite loop. Its the immediate page that opens without any loading.

Comment: @JanBo double check the root directory and see if there is any htaccess file there (or in any of the subdirectories)